# While loop not looping and storing in dictionary

Tags: python, while-loop

Everytime it will return a single last item entered from the input. Am a newbie into coding and python, sorry if it's a stupid question.

```
cars = {}

while True:
   models = input('Please enter car model name: ')
   colors = input('Please enter car color: ')
   cars[models] = colors
   another = input('Do you want to register another car? (y/n): ')
   if another == 'y':
       continue
   else:
       break

print(cars)
```

It returns:

```
Please enter car model name: bmw
Please enter car color: red
Do you want to register another car? (y/n): y
Please enter car model name: bmw
Please enter car color: blue
Do you want to register another car? (y/n): y
Please enter car model name: merc
Please enter car color: black
Do you want to register another car? (y/n): n
{'bmw': 'blue', 'merc': 'black'}
```

It didn't return the {'bmw':'red'}

Comment: The block that starts with `another =` and end with `break` should be indented to be inside of the while loop.

Comment: Sorry, edited the post. The another= is indented in my code.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  I ran your code and I get a dictionary with multiple cars and colors (after entering multiple cars and colors).  If you want to be able to have cars of the same model but different colors, I'd suggest making this a list of tuples instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter the same model multiple times, the previous color for that model will be overwritten in the dictionary. That's because a dictionary will only save one value for a given key.

Try giving different models and you'll have multiple key/value pairs.

```
Please enter car model name: ford
Please enter car color: blue
Do you want to register another car? (y/n): y
Please enter car model name: chevy
Please enter car color: red
Do you want to register another car? (y/n): n
{'ford': 'blue', 'chevy': 'red'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want, is to store multiple colors for each provided model?

In that case, consider using list appending, instead of value assignment.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

cars = defaultdict(list)

while True:
   model = input('Please enter car model name: ')
   color = input('Please enter car color: ')
   cars[model].append(color)

   another = input('Do you want to register another car? (y/n): ')
   if another != 'y':
      break

print(cars)
```

In case you want to store list of sets "model, color", use list instead of dict, since dict can store only one (latest) value for same key.

```py
cars = []

while True:
   model = input('Please enter car model name: ')
   color = input('Please enter car color: ')
   cars.append([model, color])

   another = input('Do you want to register another car? (y/n): ')
   if another != 'y':
      break

print(cars)
```

If you combine one of the variants with some sort of structure (e.g. [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or [`Dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), you can have more structured list with named properties

Answer (score -2):

```
cars = {}
def inputcars():
    models = input('Please enter car model name: ')
    colors = input('Please enter car color: ')
    cars[models] = colors
    another = input('Do you want to register another car? (y/n): ')
    if another == 'y':
        inputcars()


inputcars()
print(cars)

Please enter car model name: ford
Please enter car color: red
Do you want to register another car? (y/n): y
Please enter car model name: subaru
Please enter car color: blue
Do you want to register another car? (y/n): n
{'ford': 'red', 'subaru': 'blue'}
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: original code was broken due to indentation outside of while loop, i provided alternative